# PHP CLI script run as cron dies on caught exceptions

Tags: php, exception, cron

I have a PHP script that runs as a cron. When an exception is thrown it executes the catch block then dies. If I run the same script in the cli, not as a cron job, it runs the catch block and continues run the rest of the script. Any idea why this would be?

Here is where the exception thrown:

```
public static function concurrentGet($urlList, $callback, $passthrough = null) {
    //init the guzzle client
    $client = new Client([
        "headers" => [
            "Accept" => "text/html,text/json,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Accept-Encoding" => "gzip, deflate, sdch",
            "Accept-Language" => "en-US",
            "Cache-Control" => "no-cache",
            "Connection" => "keep-alive",
            "Pragma" => "no-cache",
            "User-Agent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36"
        ],
        'debug' => false,
        "verify" => false,
        "cookies" => true
    ]);
    //this function is called by the pool to generate request objects
    $requests = function ($urlList) {
        foreach ($urlList as $url) {
            yield new Request('GET', $url);
        }
    };
    //execute the pool of requests
    $pool = new Pool($client, $requests($urlList), [
        'concurrency' => 5,
        'fulfilled' => function ($response, $index) use ($urlList, $callback, $passthrough) {
            $url = $urlList[$index];
            //$app['logger']->info("GET: $url...");
            $body = $response->getBody()->getContents();

            //call passed callback
            call_user_func(
                $callback,
                $body,
                $url,
                $passthrough
            );

        },
        'rejected' => function (\Exception $reason, $index) use ($urlList, $callback, $passthrough) {
            $url = $urlList[$index];
            echo "REJECT: ".$url."\n";
            //echo "REASON: ".$reason."\n"; 

            throw $reason;

        },
    ]);
```

Here is how it is caught:

```
                try {
                $report->concurrentGet($report->OSRMRequests, [$report, 'OSRMCallback']);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                //send to airbrake
                Airbrake\Instance::notify($e);
                //log to internal application log
                $app['errorLog']->error($e->getMessage());

            }

*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php ~/Projects/easyivmr/bin/console createreport >> /var/log/ivmr_report.log
```

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS.

Comment: Paste the cronjob and the CLI command in the question too.

Comment: Also which distribution are you using? `Cron` is kind of buggy, maybe you can use `systemd`'s `service`/`unit` files with a `timer`?

Comment: I added the command to the original question under the try-catch block.

Comment: @user2626294 and you call the exact same command when you do it manually in the console?

Comment: Yes, exact same command.